# Web Activity Issue In Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Getiing Below Error While Executing my pipeline.

Error

{
    "errorCode": "2108",
    "message": "Error calling the endpoint. Response status code: ",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Web1"
}

Here is My Code:

{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Web1",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "url": "http://00.00.00.00:8000/name?env=DEV",
                    "method": "GET"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

Comment: how your response from web activity look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have entered valid “url–Target endpoint and path”.

I have tried with valid url and the Job was successful.

**JSON Code for the web activity:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Webactivity",
                "type": "WebActivity",
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "url": "https://www.microsoft.com/",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "body": ""
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Web Activity which is succeeded.

[image]

For more details, refer “[Web activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity)”.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your update but i got the issue here: Web Activity required Public end point but we are using Private vnet where we can not allow public end point that's the issue.